# What will be the output of following and why?

Tags: javascript

What will the following output and why

`let user = "Brienne of Tarth"; "Sansa Stark"; "Lyanna Mormont";` chrome print last one & when I access user it show the first one. why it happens

Comment: The `;` separates individual statements. `user` is assigned `"Brienne of Tarth"` in the first statement. The last statement is `"Lyanna Marmont"` which has the value... `"Lyanna Marmont"`, so that's what Chrome shows (the last statement value).

Comment: As @lurker says, there are three expressions here. Running them all on one line will execute them in order and return whatever the last expression evaluates to. So it first declares `user` and assigns it a value, then it evaluates two (useless) standalone string expressions and returns the result of the last one, `"Lyanna Mormont"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical REPL (read-eval-print loop) the thing that gets printed is simply whatever the last statement executed evaluated to. You have three statements:

```
let user = "Brienne of Tarth";
"Sansa Stark";
"Lyanna Mormont";
```

The first one is a variable assignment, and the last two are just string expressions that do nothing on their own but are still valid statements.

If you put this in the console Chrome simply prints the value of the last statement ("Lyanna Mormont").